# How to gracefully shutdown or close Node.Js Express app

Tags: node.js, docker, express, graceful-shutdown

#### Motivation

I want to ensure there is no brute (sub-)process termination and that any open requests are fulfilled when the Express server is closing.

```
import express, { Express, Request, Response } from 'express';

// Initialize the Express server application
var app = express();
var server = this.app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => { ... } );

// POST endpoint to process the shopping cart
app.post('/purchase', async (req, res) => {
  // Get the items from the request body

  try {
      const { buyer, items } = req.body;
      
      // Process the items (e.g., calculate total price, initiate payment, etc.)
      const totalPrice = calculateTotalPrice(items);
      // Charge the buyer for the purchase
      const payment = chargeBuyerForPurchase(totalPrice);
      
      //  I don't want the server to close before it executes this line for every request

      // Create shipping for the purchased items
      const shipping = carrierAPI.createShipping(items, buyer.address);

      res.status(200).json([totalPrice, payment, shipping]);

      // ‍♂️ This is now safe to close the server
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }

});
```

#### Proposed Solution

[See documentation at this link](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#serverclosecallback)

```
// ./src/app.ts
import process from 'node:process';

// Begin reading from stdin so the process does not exit.
process.stdin.resume();

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  console.log('Received SIGINT. Press Control-D to exit.');
});

// FYI docker "stop" <container>, a process manager, and most hosts will send SIGTERM signal when it is shutting down.
// server.close stops the server from accepting new connections and closes all connections connected to this server that are not sending a request or waiting for a response

function gracefulClose(signal) {
  console.log(`Received ${signal}`);
  server.close( () => { log('HTTP(S) server closed') } );

}

process.on('SIGINT', gracefulClose);
process.on('SIGTERM', gracefulClose);
```

Is it a feature to implement? Is this feature / code redundant?

Comment: This won't work, because it attempts to create a duplicate of your toplevel `var server` object. You need to use that same object in `server.close()`.

Comment: Thank you for checking this. I made a sort of a typo. I meant to use the same `server` instance.

So, is it a correct approach to ensure all open connections are properly closed before the server application exit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### THESE ARE MY FINDINGS:

1. When the `SIGTERM` signal is emitted, the Node.JS server will be immediately closed. The Node.Js application / process will still be alive. Moreover, a response will not be sent to any client even if its connection was open before the `SIGTERM` signal was received.
2. When the `SIGINT` signal is emitted, the Node.JS (Express) server and application or process will be immediately closed.
3. When a custom signal is emitted, `SIGUSR1` or `SIGUSR2`, the Node.JS server will immediately close any open connections. The Node.Js application / process will still be alive. The Node.Js (Express) server will still be alive too and fulfill only new requests and responses.

PS: Signals are ***software interrupts*** sent to a program to indicate that an important event has occurred. Another common method for delivering signals is to use the `kill` command, the syntax of which is as follows −

```
$ kill -signal <pid>
```

#### MY SOLUTION:

I have created an npm package to [super-gracefully-shutdown][1] your Node.Js Express server. It ensures a response is sent to every client for any connections that were open before you send a super-graceful `shutdown` message.

### Usage / Implementation

```
import express from 'express';
import SGS from 'super-graceful-shutdown';

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

const express = require('express');
const SGS = require('super-graceful-shutdown');

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const port = 80; // Set your desired port number

// ...

router.get('/api', async function(req, res, next){
  try {
      // Fulfill this request in 3 seconds
      setTimeout(() => { res.status(200).send(`<html> <body> <h1>${date()}</h1> </body> </html>`)  }, 3000);
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
});

const server = app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example Express app listening on port ${port}!`) );

// ℹ️ Before you initialize other routes, you need to initialize super-graceful-shutdown
new SGS(app, server);

// ‍ Then, you can initialize other routes
app.use('/', router);
```

### Request From Host To Shutdown Node.Js Express App

To super-gracefully-shutdown your Node.Js Express application, send the TCP `shutdown` message on port 3000:

```
echo "shutdown" | nc localhost 3000
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Handle SIGTERM to permit Docker to cause a graceful exit

With respect to Docker, yes you have to handle the SIGTERM event and gracefully exit.  If you do not, then after having signalled your container to exit, Docker will wait for some period of time (10 sec, I believe) for your container to exit, and if it does not do so in time, Docker will forcibly kill your container.

In general, this would be sufficient:

```
process.on('SIGTERM', process.exit);
process.on('SIGINT', process.exit);
```

#### You can't handle SIGTERM events during synchronous code anyway

In your example code, your *post* handler is **synchronous**.  JavaScript is single threaded and cannot run your `gracefulClose` handler (in response to the `SIGTERM` event) until your synchronous function has completed.  So your code is unnecessary *in this case*.  If the *post* handler function were *asynchronous*, then you'd have to a different situation.

#### Deferring a graceful exit during an asynchronous operation

If you were to modify your post handler to be asynchronous, such that you could have a reason not to exit and possibly have the SIGTERM handler run before your reason not to exit is resolved, then **yes**, you'd have to implement something special to handle that.

Such an implementation might go like this:

Any time you create a situation that constitutes a reason to prevent forcibly closing, push an object representing that reason into an array.  When the situation no longer exists, remove the reason from the array.

When you get a SIGTERM signal, set a flag saying that you want to exit.

Then write a function that checks to see if it's ok to exit.  The condition will be that you have set the exit flag, and the reasons-not-to-exit array is empty.  If it's ok to exit, then you may call `process.exit`.

Call this function after setting the exit flag, and also call it after removing a reason from the array.

```
const reasonsNotToExit = [];
let isExitRequested = false;

function requestGracefulExit() {
  isExitRequested = true;
  exitIfRequired();
}

function exitIfRequired() {
  if (isExitRequested && resonsNotToExit.length == 0) {
    process.exit();
  }
}

process.on('SIGINT', requestGracefulExit);
process.on('SIGTERM', requestGracefulExit);
```

Example deferral:  (for example, in the body of your *post* handler.)

```
   // Add a reason not to exit
   let reason = {};
   reasonsNotToExit.push(reason);

   // Imagine some async thing that should cause graceful exits to be deferred:
   // note use of `await`
   const shipping = await carrierAPI.createShipping(items, buyer.address);
   // ... and now imagine that the reason not to exit has been resolved.

   // Remove the reason from the array.
   reasonsNotToExit.splice(reasonsNotToExit.indexOf(reason), 1);
   // We are obligated to call this when we remove a reason:
   exitIfRequired();
```

**Note** that this example has explicitly awaited some hypothetical async operation using `await`, which is missing from your original example, in which this code was not necessary.

**Note** that even though you've coded up something to handle a graceful exit, after politely asking your container to exit, Docker essentially starts a doomsday timer, and it may forcibly terminate your program after 10 seconds anyway, whether you've finished cleaning up or not.  Also `docker kill` will ungracefully terminate your program, even if this code is in place.

Comment: I have fixed my code to execute the router handler function asynchronously. You did a great catch!

All of my <POST> requests take less than 10 seconds to be fulfilled. So, the approach you have provided will work for me.

Moreover, can you architect the code to create a middle-man that tracks all post requests that are not fulfilled in an array?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can create a middle-man that tracks any post requests that *you* initiate.  That's the second code block in my answer with the `await carrierAPI.createShipping` part replaced with awaiting a _post_ of your choice. you can imagine crafting a `postAndDeferExit` function that brackets an awaited _post_ call with the code provided in the second code block.